# Time until which zookeeper assumes a node in cluster to be dead

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I was recently reading about that it is recommended to run zookeeper with odd number of nodes. So, in a cluster of 3 nodes, it can tolerate upto 2 failures. But what if I start a 3 node cluster and just remove one of the node , so at what part of time will it consider it to be a 2 node cluster? Or is this a hack to run it in a 2 node cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast (ZAB)  handles electing a leader and recovery of failing leaders and nodes.

To detect failures, Zab employs periodic heartbeat messages between followers and their leaders. If a leader does not receive heartbeats from a quorum of followers within a given timeout, it abandons its leadership and shifts to state election.

The protocol iteration are:

Phase 0 –  prospective leader election

Phase 1 – discovery

Phase 2 – synchronization

Phase 3 – broadcast

In your case, starting with three nodes and then losing one, you have to distinguish the cases:

A - the lost node was the leader
B - the lost node wasn't the leader

In A, everything continues with no problem.
In B, phase 0 starts again.

Take a look to this reference for details on ZAB: 
https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.12/zookeeperInternals.html